# Is the gravitational field stronger in the transverse plane of a mass than along its axis of propagation?

Tags: forces, gravity, field-theory

Is the gravitational field stronger in the transverse plane of a mass than along its axis of propagation?   I read somewhere that it was but cannot find the reference again. That is, for a mass traveling at very high velocity, or any velocity I suppose, I read that the gravitational force was stronger in the transverse plane of the mass than it is along its axis of propagation, and wanted to know if this was correct.

Comment: What is the "transverse plane of a mass?" And, what is being "propagated?"

Answer (score 0):

If "transverse plane of mass" means the gravitational attraction perpendicular to the mass's velocity, then you are correct.

There is a weak field approximation to GR call [Gravitoelectromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) in which there is an $\vec{E_G}$ and $\vec{B_G}$ which obey equations similar to Maxwell's equations for $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ of electromagnetism.   $\vec{E_G}$ is the acceleration caused by a mass (eg: for a mass M at rest $\vec{E_G}=\frac{-GM\hat{e_r}}{r^2}$), and  $\vec{B_G}$ is the angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$ that a spinning mass with angular momentum causes to other objects.

$\vec{E_G}$ and $\vec{B_G}$ transform just like $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ when viewed from a velocity boosted frame. Therefore, if we boost an at rest mass that is not spinning (ie: $\vec{B_G}=0$), we get

$$
\begin{align}
\
     E'_{G \ parallel} &=E_{G \ parallel} \\
E'_{G \ perpendicular} &=\gamma E_{G \ perpendicular}
\end{align}
$$

The field lines of $\vec{E'_G}$ (ie: acceleration) are bunched out perpendicular to the boost direction.  I think this is the effect you read about.

Comment: As far as the slightly weaker gravitational field that exists along               E′G parallel =E'G parallel, i.e., along the mass's axis of propagation, or parallel to its axis of propagation, is there any difference in the strength of this slightly weaker gravitational field between the "front" and "back" of the mass, i.e., toward the direction it is moving, and toward the direction from which it came, or anatomically, between its anterior and posterior aspects with respect to its direction of movement?  Thank you kind sir.

Comment: Because $\gamma = (1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})^{-1/2}$, there is no difference for $+v$ or $-v$. However, be sure to be at the distances (which are different for front and back) in the new frame that correspond to the same r in the mass's rest frame.